# The English Tense in Passive Voice

Tags: passive-voice

Yesterday I read *Modern English:A Practical Reference Guide* written by Marcella Frank, and she gives a paradigm about tenses on page 50. The page shows tenses in active voice and passive voice; she said these four tenses are exceedingly rare:

1. shall/will be being offered
2. has/have been being offered
3. had been being offered
4. shall/will have been being offered

Why are these tense so rare? Are they normally replaced by other tenses?

Comment: These tenses are rare because native English speakers don't use them, and many people probably consider them ungrammatical. See [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35784/can-the-present-perfect-continuous-construct-be-used-in-passive-voice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those constructions are all rare because they are too cumbersome, and so shorter constructions are used instead. It is exquisitely difficult to construct a contextual framework in which the longer version would make more sense than the shorter one.

They are also too confusing. All those markers of a continuous aspect are superfluous in all but the rarest of circumstances, especially when combined with a completed aspect.

### 1. *shall/will be being offered*

This should normally be simply *shall/will be offered* without the *being* part:

- It’s not being offered now.
- It will be offered later.
- We will be offering that later on.

### 2. *has/have been being offered*

### 3. *had been being offered*

These two try to combine a perfect construction (*have* + past participle) with a continuous aspect (*be* + present participle).  The speaker should make up their mind about whether the action is completed or continuing.

- It hasn’t been offered lately.
- It hadn’t been offered yet.
- It wasn’t offered yet.
- It wasn’t being offered yet.
- It hadn’t been offered yet.
- We weren’t offering that then.
- We hadn’t been offering that way back then. (*poor*)
- We didn’t offer that way back then. (*better*)
- We weren’t offering that way back then. (*also better*)

### 4. *shall/will have been being offered*

This has the same problem as before: a confusion of continuous and completed aspects. Use only one.

- It will be offered then.
- We will be offering it later.
- It will have already been offered by then.