# Grammar - Passive

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

> The famous artist will have been painting the mural for over six months by the time it is finished

Is it correct to convert the above sentence to "passive" form as follows?

> The mural will have been being painted by the famous artist for over six months by the time it is finished.

P.S. I've been learning about converting sentences to passive and came accross the sentence that I mentioned.

Comment: Looks alright grammatically, but the result sounds a bit ungainly.

Comment: So ungainly, in fact, that a wiser person would condescend to use the active voice there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [*The English Tense in Passive Voice*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218205/the-english-tense-in-passive-voice). Note particularly the first comment: *These tenses are rare because native English speakers don't use them, and many people probably consider them ungrammatical*. See also [*Can the present perfect continuous construct be used in passive voice?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35784/)

Comment: People almost never use *been being*. You could dispense with *been being* but keep the mural as the subject of the sentence if, for example, you replaced *being painted by* with *under the brush of*.